# Delegate crash when I release the view because don't found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the next issue I'm creating one view when one button is touched. when the view is created and loaded I make 2  request with `ASIFormDataRequest` one request for download one Image and the other for get some text.

The headache become when the user in the view loaded select back because if button back is pressed the view is removed form superview, but crashh if one request callback is coming and the view dont exist how can I make this like cancel the request or how can I fix that.

The crash is in the next line of code

Class: ASIHTTPRequest.m

```
    BOOL dataWillBeHandledExternally = NO;
    **if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:[self didReceiveDataSelector]]) {**
        dataWillBeHandledExternally = YES;
    }
```

With: **Thread 6: EXC_BAD_ACCES (code = 1, address = 0x30047dbc)**

Please hellp that has haunted me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make sure that you cancel any pending `ASIHTTPRequest` when you pop your view:
From: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#cancelling_an_asychronous_request

```
// Cancels an asynchronous request, clearing all delegates and blocks first
[request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
```

Comment: Ho my god thanks very much @ckhan really thanks you solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch for it. below is how u can do in ASIHTTPRequest.m

```
@try {
        if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:[self didReceiveDataSelector]]) {
            dataWillBeHandledExternally = YES;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        dataWillBeHandledExternally = NO;
    }
```